# Arachni on Mac OS X Catalina

Tags: macos

**Arachni** is a feature-full, modular, high-performance Ruby framework aimed towards helping penetration testers and administrators evaluate the security of modern web applications, I never use it before I heard a lot of good things about it, so I tried to installed and run it.

I'm on a Mac OS X 10.15
I just recent downloaded **Arachni** from [here](https://www.arachni-scanner.com/download/)

Then, I got this on my **Download** folder

[image]

I extracted it, and renamed it to `Arachni`

[image]

[image]

I had to go allow it manually

[image]

I allowed one, 3 more come up

[image]

Restart the command,

`$  ./bin/arachni`

I got the permission prompt again

[image]

If someone know how to get this working on latest Mac OS X, please let me know.

Answer (score 5):

A bit late but I'm providing the solution anyway since it's quite straightforward if you know a few macOS tricks (which is not always so easy, though).

So how do you stop macOS Gatekeeper from bugging you with all those requests?

Just run `sudo xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine *` inside arachni folder and you're good to go.

Also, related to your question, you have to raise the number of opened files else arachni will complain when connecting to a website and basically not work properly.

On macOS (I'm on Catalina) you do: `ulimit -n 1024`.

Here a complete sequence of commands for your convenience:

```
cd arachni-1.5.1-0.5.12
sudo xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine *
ulimit -n 1024
./bin/arachni_web
```

Comment: Late better than never ;P, Thanks for answering :)